# Ajax MSSQL query using json and php returns undefined array

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, json

I have a problem when i alert( data[i].name). The result is undefined even if the array is returned. Anyone knows what the problem is?

This is My Javascript

```
    $('#plus').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'jqueryDBactionview.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { },
        success: function( data){
            $.each( data, function(i, item) {
                alert( data[i].name);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my php

```
$query = "SELECT TOP (1) * ";
$query .= "FROM maillist WHERE bolag = 'FAL'";
$results = mssql_query($query);
$result = array();
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($results))
{
  $result[] = array(
          'id' => $row['id'],
          'company' => $row['company'],
          'name' => $row['name'],
          'mail' => $row['mail']
       );
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: you have `data: { }` empty...

Answer (score 0):

Please use JSON.parse(data) to convert your json encoded result and then use it in your each loop

Comment: data {} is used to send the post variables with the Ajax request which is empty, but data is parameter of the success function, so whatever value is returned by Mysql $result is passed to data parameter of function

Comment: why use post ???it should be get method , the questioner does not post anything to server

Comment: and also i hope i sql query is also not in good format , i never work in php but in standard way it seems to be wrong